# How to create a resizeable TinyMCE textarea?

Tags: django, django-forms, tinymce

I have a Django form using textareas and TinyMCE for text entry.

I would like to add a slider to change the vertical size of the textarea, like SO has them so nicely.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add 'theme_advanced_resizing : true' In the tyniMCE init call

Comment: This works, even though it does not look as nice as on SO. However, I had to add these items as well:

    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : 'bottom',
    theme_advanced_path : false,
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,
    theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : false,
    theme_advanced_resizing_use_cookie : true,

Comment: The only additional property you have to set is the status bar location, for example: theme_advanced_statusbar_location : 'bottom'

Comment: I'm working on a CakePHP 2.x app and was able to just add `'theme_advanced_resizing' => true` to my Tinymce input array.

Comment: It can work on any server language and framework, as long as you can pass options to the JS library